# Can my employer access my server share folder within my virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, shared-folders

I do lots of contract work for various clients/companies. The way I keep everything separated is that I create a new Hyper-V Virtual Machine on my server, install Windows and set it up with the work account/email they provide me. This works fine, often times that Hyper-V Virtual Machine is automatically provisioned and gains access to their code repository, etc.

When I'm setting up the virtual machine I give it access to a drive where I keep all my developer tools and the such. I'm wondering if the client/company can see my share drive and possibly even access it?

I guess this might have two answers? If the virtual machine is not connected to their domain (I simply use the credentials to log into the machine), and if the virtual machine is connected to their domain somehow?

How far can they get into my machine or network?

Comment: Some things aren't clear to me in your question.  Can your employer log into the VM as a valid user?  Are they an admin on that VM?  If you were to simply using networking and permissions to access your dev tools, this wouldn't be a problem (assuming you didn't share your credentials).

Comment: Set your Hyper-V machine to Bridged Connection and and that will facilitate connect in.  I did such connecting to my Hyper-V machine from my other machine and that worked.